# Python27 - PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to convert a .ui file generated in Qt4 into python executable file.
I've tried installing pyqt4 dev tools by the following command:

pip install pyqt4-dev-tools

But found an exception as follows:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt4-dev-tools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt4-dev-tools.

Will be pleased if anyone provides a solution.Thank you.

Comment: Hello welcome to Stack overflow please consider showing your effort and add code to the question.  
Try researching in how to add deprecated packages to pip or searching for some archived repositories where it is available

Comment: `pyqt4-dev-tools` is the name given to you by ubuntu and other debian-based distributions for the PyQt4 package, but pip does not use that name, if you are using ubuntu or similar, just run: `sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools`

Comment: Thank you @eyllanse. I've tried in linux it was working properly. Now am working with Windows platform. Any suggestions for windows?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, if you installed PyQt4 package already, you should have the pyuic tool available. You can call it with using`python C:\Python\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py UIFileName.ui -o PythonFileName.py -x`